# Unions and intersections, where the answer is infinite?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

A ∪ (C ∩ B)

where $C$ is a set of even integers, while $B$ is a set of odd integers.
$$A = \{ -3,1,2,4,0,17\}$$
you would assume that it would be an empty set, but the answer is infinite, why is that??

Comment: It is neither... If $C$ was the entire set of even integers and $B$ was the entire set of odd integers, then $\{-3,1,2,4,0,17\}\cap (C\cup B) = \{-3,1,2,4,0,17\}\cap \Bbb Z = \{-3,1,2,4,0,17\}$

Comment: but my teacher answered it, he says infinite?

Comment: There is a comma after the $17$ in your description, did you mean $A$ to contain more than $6$ elements?

Comment: Make sure you copy the **exact** wording of the question with the *exact* symbols used

Comment: oooh my bad its A∪ (C  ∩  B) like this, and the comma wasnt meant to be there, just edited it

Comment: Did you mean to say $C$ is the set of even integers and $B$ is the set of odd integers? When you say "with even integers" that doesn't necessarily mean it contains *only* even integers, nor does it mean it contains *all* even integers.

Comment: yeah! i edited it

Comment: In that case the answer is still equal to $A$ since $C\cap B=\varnothing$.

Comment: yeah, but my teacher says  its actually infinite?

Comment: Ask your teacher to explain their answer then, that is wrong.

Comment: i cant, its a question  posted online, and my finals tmrw

Comment: In your posting the question has gone from $A\cap (B\cup C)$ to $A\cup(B\cap C)$ which are two very different questions (with the same answer).  If you teacher said the answer is infinite, I have to assume the teacher was asking yet third different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A\subset \mathbb Z$.

$B = \{$ odd integers$\}$,  $C=\{$ even integers $\}$

Question 1:  What is $A \cap (B\cup C)$.

Answer:  $B\cup C = \{x| x\in B$ or $x \in C\} = \{x| x$ is an odd integer or $x$ is an even integer$\}= \{x|x \in \mathbb Z\} = \mathbb Z$.

$A\cap (B\cup C) = A\cap \mathbb Z = \{x|x \in A; x \in \mathbb Z\}$.  As $A\subset \mathbb Z$ then every $x \in A$ will be $x\in \mathbb Z$ so $A\cap \mathbb Z = A$.

Question 2: What is $A\cup (B\cap C)$?

$B\cap C = \{x|x\in B$ and $x \in C\} = \{x|x$ is an odd integer and $x$ is an even integer $\}= \emptyset$.

$A \cup (B\cap C)= A\cup \emptyset =\{x|x \in A$ or $x\in \emptyset\}$.  As *nothing* is in $\emptyset$ this is the same as $\{x|x\in A\} = A$.

Basically $M \cup \emptyset = M$.  That should be a universal truth that should be as obvious to you as saying "water is wet" and "pain hurts".

If $M \subset K$ then $M \cap K = M$.  That should also be a universal truth and as obvious as saying.  "If ice cream is a food, then it is ice cream".

(We also have $M\cap \emptyset= \emptyset$ ... "There isnt anything that is nothing".  ANd if $M\subset K$ then $M \cup K$ .... "You can have a sandwich or you can have food; either way you're going to have food".)

Question 3:  What is $A\cup (B\cup C)$?

$A\cup (B\cup Z) = A\cup \mathbb Z = \mathbb Z$.

Question 4:  What is $A\cap (B\cap C)$?

$A\cap (B\cap Z) = A \cap \emptyset = \emptyset$.

Question 5:  What is $(A\cap B)\cup C$?

$A\cap B = \{x|x \in A$ and $x$ is an odd integer$\} = \{-3,1,17\}$ and $(A\cap B) \cup C = \{-3,1,17\}\cup C= \{x|$ either $x =-3,1,$ or $17$ or $x$ is an even number = {.....,-10,-8,-6,-4,-3,-2,0,1,2,4,6,...,12,14,16,17,18,20,22,....}$.

Question 6: What is $(A\cup B)\cap C$?

$(A \cup B) = \{x\in A$ or $x$ is an odd integer$\} = \{$odd integers as well as $2,4,$ and $0\}$.

$(A\cup B) \cap C = \{x|x$ is an odd integer or $2,4,$ or $0$ but also $x$ must be an ever integer$\} = \{2,4,0\}$

Question 7: What is $(A\cap B) \cap C$.

That is what are the elments of $A$ that are also odd integers And are also even integers = $-3,1,17$ and also even integers = nothing = $\emptyset$

Qustion 8: What is $(A \cup B) \cup C$.

What is in $A$ or an odd integer?  That is any odd integer but also possibly $0,2,$ or $4$.

And what is all that but possibly an even integer?  So it can be an even integer, an odd integer or one of the integgers of $A$?  That could be any integer.  SO $(A\cup B) \cup C = \mathbb Z$.

....

SO what question was your teacher asking about?

I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $\forall a\in A, a\not\in B,$ so $C\cap B=\emptyset$ and $A\cup (C\cap B)=A\cup \emptyset=A.$